# Working of TypedValue in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, interface, android-edittext

When we want to change the width of a EditText in Android, we use this line of code:

int px=(int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,200,r.getDisplayMetrics());

Can someone explain how this works and what does TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP return?

Comment: TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP returns 1

Answer (score 5):

COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP specifies what measurement unit does the number refer to. What you wrote translates to "200 DIP". I believe you know what DIP is. If it was COMPLEX_UNIT_SP then the 200 would be translated as "200 SP"

Here is the source code of applyDimension:

```
public static float applyDimension(int unit, float value,
                                       DisplayMetrics metrics)
    {
        switch (unit) {
        case COMPLEX_UNIT_PX:
            return value;
        case COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP:
            return value * metrics.density;
        case COMPLEX_UNIT_SP:
            return value * metrics.scaledDensity;
        case COMPLEX_UNIT_PT:
            return value * metrics.xdpi * (1.0f/72);
        case COMPLEX_UNIT_IN:
            return value * metrics.xdpi;
        case COMPLEX_UNIT_MM:
            return value * metrics.xdpi * (1.0f/25.4f);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: And what does r.getDisplayMetrics() do?

Comment: DisplayMetris is a class you can use to get information or do calculations related to screen size and resolution. Translating DIP,DP,SP etc is based on the screen's specs. Also when an answer is satisfying you accept it not upvote it. Upvote is for everyone else except the person who posted the question.